# Help me to derive the derivative for $(Ax-b)^T(Ax-b)$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, self-learning, matrix-calculus

I know the derivative of  $(Ax-b)^T(Ax-b)$ is $A^TAx-A^Tb$, but it seems something wrong with my own derivation. Please help me find the error. Thanks

$$
(Ax-b)^T(Ax-b)=(x^TA^T-b^T)(Ax-b)=x^TA^TAx-x^TA^Tb-b^TAx+b^Tb$$

So, taking the derivative with all four terms respect to $x$, we get

$$
(A^TA+(A^TA)^T)x-A^Tb-b^TA+0
$$

what's wrong there?

---

Edit: with Siong Thye Goh and Bernard's help I got the error, and would like to provide the right derivation here for my own future reference.
$$
\begin{align}
(Ax-b)^T(Ax-b)&=(x^TA^T-b^T)(Ax-b)\\
&=x^TA^TAx-x^TA^Tb-b^TAx+b^Tb \\
&=x^T(A^TA)x-x^T(A^Tb)-(b^TA)x+b^Tb
\end{align}
$$

We need to recall two rules:

$$\frac {\partial(a^Tx)} {\partial x}=\frac {\partial(x^Ta)} {\partial x}=a$$

$$\frac {\partial(x^TAx)} {\partial x}=(A+A^T)x$$

Then, take the derivative respect to $x$ we have

$$
\begin{align}
(A^TA+(A^TA)^T)x-2A^Tb&=2A^TAx-2A^Tb\\
&=2A^T(Ax-b)
\end{align}
$$

Comment: If you mean the derivative with respect to $x$ (as opposed to that with respect to $b$) it would be a good idea to say so.  If you're looking for the value of $x$ that minimizes the product, that can be done without finding the derivative.  Others please note in case you're not aware of it: this product is typically considered when $A$ is a matrix having many more rows than columns, so that $b$ is not generally in the column space of $A$. $\qquad$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expected answer is wrong to begin with, it should be $$2(A^TAx-A^Tb)$$

Also, the sizes of $A^Tb$ and $b^TA$ are different, aren't they?

Comment: thanks for catching this error. I forget the constant 2 because that does not affect setting derivative to 0. Could you tell me more about the error on $A^Tb$ and $b^TA$ thanks again!!

Comment: $A^Tb$ is column vector but $b^TA$ is a row vector, so they can't be subtracted.

Comment: but $x^TA^Tb=b^TAx$, so I believe you can solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks. I think I get it now!

Answer (score 2):

Note the derivative of $Ax-b$ is $A$ and the derivative of $\;{}^{\mathrm t\mkern-1.5mu}(Ax-b)$ is  $\;{}^{\mathrm t\mkern-1.5mu}A$ since it is the composition of $Ax-b$ with the *linear* operator of transposition. Thus the derivative of the given expression is
\begin{align*}
{}^{\mathrm t\!}A(Ax-b)+{}^{\mathrm t\mkern-2mu}(Ax-b)A&=
({}^{\mathrm t\!}A A)x-{}^{\mathrm t\!}Ab+{}^{\mathrm t\mkern-2mu}x({}^{\mathrm t\!}AA)-.
\end{align*}
Now observe that, since ${}^{\mathrm t\mkern-3mu}AA$ is symmetric, $\;{}^{\mathrm t\mkern-2mu}x({}^{\mathrm t\!}AA)=({}^{\mathrm t\!}AA)x$. Thus the derivative is
$$2{\,}^{\mathrm t\!}AAx-{}^{\mathrm t\!}Ab-{}^{\mathrm t\mkern-1mu}bA.$$